# SQL query to find leaves in a tree

Tags: sql, activerecord, tree

I'm storing a tree in Postgres linked via a parent_id column.  I want to find the leaves of the tree, as in, those elements that have no children.  Here's the query I have so far:

```
where("id NOT IN ( SELECT parent_id FROM elements WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL )")
```

Is there a better way to write this query?  I was trying to think of a way to handle it with a join, as I've heard that's more efficient, but wasn't able to come up with anything.  Also, is there a way to do this without raw SQL and instead use ActiveRecord?

**UPDATE:**  Here's the schema:

```
   Column   |            Type             |     Modifiers      
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------
 id         | character varying(36)       | not null
 user_id    | character varying(36)       | not null
 parent_id  | character varying(36)       | 
 title      | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "index_elements_on_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
    "index_elements_on_parent_id" btree (parent_id)
    "index_elements_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

Comment: I think you can use this to execute SQL, ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) but I don't know if it will increase performance for sure.

Comment: can you paste the description of the tables you're using?

Comment: Just as a hint for your next question. When posting table definitions or sample data, post it as SQL statements (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO) thus it's easier to setup a test-bed te verify the answer before posting

Comment: If anything I'd like to avoid executing raw SQL, and instead rely on ActiveRecord scoping.  There's some irony, I suppose in trying to find a more efficient query when I want to use a less efficient abstraction.  I guess my biggest concern is reducing database load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique is called "exclusion join".

```
select e.* from elements e
left outer join elements leafs
on e.id = leafs.parent_id
where leafs.parent_id is null
```

Comment: What happens if you benchmark the sub select first? Benchmarking SQL can be tricky since a lot of caching is involved. Can you compare the execution plans?